# Frama-C Install Errors

Tags: c, frama-c

I have the newest Frama-C .zip file from the website, unpacked it and ran `./configure`. That seems to have gone alright but when I run `sudo make` I get:

```
$ sudo make
Ocamlc       external/unz.cmo
File "external/unz.ml", line 39, characters 10-19:
Error: Unbound module Z
make: *** [external/unz.cmo] Error 2
```

When I run `sudo make install` I get this:

```
install: cannot stat ‘src/kernel/unroll_loops.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘src/misc/filter.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘src/kernel/special_hooks.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘src/logic/logic_interp.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘src/logic/infer_annotations.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘src/logic/allocates.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Metrics.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Syntactic_callgraph.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Value.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Occurrence.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/RteGen.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/From.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Users.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Constant_Propagation.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Postdominators.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Inout.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Semantic_callgraph.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Impact.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Pdg.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Scope.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Sparecode.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘/home/adam/frama-c-Sodium-20150201/lib/plugins/Slicing.o’: No such file or directory
install: cannot stat ‘src/kernel/boot.o’: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-lib] Error 1
```

Those errors continue to the same effect, it's looking for .o files that I do not have. I would have thought `./configure` or `make` would have made them although that is clearly not the case. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should not compile as root. Try `sudo make clean` then just `make`. (Unfortunately, I'm not sure this the cause of the problem.)

Comment: I tried that, it went through a lot of Ocamlc lines then ended on this: `Compiling    Qed (byte)
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create .depend: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 2
make: *** [src/wp/qed/bin/Qed.cmo] Error 2`

Comment: At this point, is there a directory `src/wp/qed/src`? If yes, can you try `touch src/wp/qed/src/.depend`.

Comment: I get permission denied but was able to execute the command as sudo. Should I rerun make now?

Comment: This is puzzling. Can you start everything again in a new directory without ever using sudo?

Comment: did you read/comply with the instructions at <http://frama-c.com/install-sodium-20150201.html>

Comment: my system is ubuntu 14.04.  I used : 'sudo apt-get install frama-c
' in a terminal.   It installed with no errors and a quick test indicates it works.  It used about 360 megs of disk space

Comment: @user3629249 yes I have complied and have attempted running `sudo apt-get install frama-c` the problem with that was it installed Fluorine, an older version while I need Sodium. @byako I re-extracted the file and ran everything without sudo, I still get errors however they are different: `~/frama-c-Sodium-20150201$ make
Ocamlc       external/unz.cmo
File "external/unz.ml", line 39, characters 10-19:
Error: Unbound module Z
make: *** [external/unz.cmo] Error 2' 
Note this was after I ran your touch command as my first attempt at make failed as well.

Comment: I'm lost. This error indicates that the `Zarith` library is missing, but unz.ml should not be compiled at all anyway. I have no idea what is happening, sorry.